# Labels are not getting displayed and image is not getting saved

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios4

I have created UILabels on toolBar, but when i try using it on iOS version 4.3 its not getting displayed..

Labels were getting displayed when deployment target was 6 but when deployment target is changed to 4.3 its not working..

and

i am using the save button to save the image in iOS 4.3 but its giving error (ie image not saved).
(in iOS 5.0 ,5.5 ,6.0 and 6.1 its working fine).

I am using these code to save the image (any one i am using).

```
 UIImage *viewImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURL]]];
NSLog(@"UIImage : %@",viewImage);
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"URL IS  %@", assetURL);
        [self assignDictonary:viewImage withURL:assetURL withMediaType:@"public.image"];

    }
}];
    [library release];
```

OR

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,(unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURL]]], self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
});
```

Can any one suggest what i have to do to display those labels on toolBar and save image code which will work for all versions on iOS.. (ie 4.3, 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, 6.1)..

Comment: where is you Label created ??

Comment: i didnt get your question..

Comment: put code of UILabel that created on ToolBar

Comment: i draged and dropped on ToolBar..

Comment: then check you properly connected it with file's Owner or not ??

Comment: they are connected properly.. its giving the problem only after changing the deployment target to iOS 4.3..

Comment: enable ARC and convert your code to ARC compatible (choose Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC), it just a guess though i know that ARC is supported from iOS 4.